# Try to do a progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I'm starting to code this year and sorry if my english is not good enough,
I have a problem with a progress bar with JS,
I have on my console an "uncaught TypeError who charge infinitly and say to me that we can charge the properties on style...
The first step was working but when the bar is supposed to become interactive it's not working

```js
const tll = gasp.timeline({
  paused: true
});

tll.to("#percent", "#bar", {
  duration: .2,
  opacity: 0,
  zIndex: -1
});

tll.to("#preloader", {
  duration: .8,
  width: "0%"
});

tll.from(".container", {
  duration: 1.5,
  y: "-150%"
}, "-=.2");

tll.to("container h1", {
  opacity: 1,
  textShadow: "12px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.23)",
  skewY: 10,
  y: "10%",
  stagger: {
    amount: .4
  }
});

var width = 1;
var bar = document.getElementById("barconfirm");
var id;

function move() {
  id = setInterval(frame, 10);
}

function frame() {
  if (width > 100) {
    clearInterval(id);
    tll.play();
  } else {
    width++;
    bar.style.width = width + "%";
    document.getElementById("percent").innerHTML = width + "%";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#percent {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Neutral Face";
}

#bar {
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

#barconfirm {
  width: 1%;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container h1 {
  font-family: 'Monument';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<body onload="move()">

  <div id="preloader">
    <div id="percent">1%</div>
    
    <div id="bar">
      <div id="barconfirm"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Leo Clemente</h1>
  </div>
```

Thanks to you all for your help, I want if you can an explanation more than just a code because I'm here to learn too and have a great day!

Comment: the code you posted does not show the error you claim - probably because you've used `<script>` INSIDE a script - fixing that issue, the error is `gasp is not defined` and `can't access property "style", bar is undefined` - so, what you'll need to do if you want that snippet to be runnable is, remove html (i.e. `<script>` from the JS section, and do the needful to have `gasp` defined

Comment: Hi and thanks to you for your reply, It's the first time I use gasp, I don't know how to define it, I move my all script in a JS page and I just put on my index page the link script.

Comment: well, I don't even know what gasp is - so you're in a better position to debug your code than I am

Answer (score 0):

The issue in passing the selector to the `tll.to` method, it accepts **ONE** selector, so choose one of yours for `tll.to("#percent", "#bar", {...})`.

It will work as well whether you choose **percent** or **bar**. Also, according to the document, the dependency variable name is `gsap`.

You can check out an online snippet from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/try-to-do-a-progress-bar-in-javascript-wvpwrw?file=/index.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time it's really nice like that! Do you know how to hide it after work?

Comment: The black screen will be disappeared once finished the loading. Do you need to hide something else?

Comment: The grey background to display my home page

Comment: The `.container` class is responsible to show the grey screen, you can remove the `background-color: gray;` or whatever styles you want.

Comment: Have a great coding day :D